# How to manage Login objects as part of security (User) object deployment in SSDT. Users not mapping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools & Visual Studio in order to version control the schema for a new database project. I wish to manage the security objects (Users, Logins) and permissions in this project. I am using Integrated Security, domain managed service accounts as logins. When publishing the project, User objects are being created which do not correctly link to an identically named Login object in the master database. In SSMS, the User objects display with a red cross. The application running under the windows login account fails to connect.

I'm unable to subsequently map the user to the login using either `ALTER` statements or `sp_update_users_login`. The `ALTER` approach completes with no errors, and `sp_update_users_login` returns an error: *"the login [..] is absent or invalid"*.

In the SSDT project, my User security objects are set like this:
`CREATE USER [DOMAIN\MSAAccount$] FOR LOGIN "DOMAIN\MSAAccount$"`

I don't completely understand the difference between `FOR LOGIN` and `FROM LOGIN` to be honest.

I know I could just strip out the security objects from this project and manage manually, but I have very fine grained restrictions set on dozens of tables and would rather this was version controlled.

Comment: You should really be using [ALTER USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). `sp_update_users_login` is in maintenance mode (and has been for some years), and will be removed in a future version of SQL Server.

Comment: ALTER USER isn't mapping the user to the login. It completes successfully, however the red cross remains.

Comment: What do you mean "the red cross"? SQL Server resultsets don't have colours.

Comment: @AlasdairC, do you see a red x in SSMS for the login, user, or both? For logins, it means the account is disabled and, for users, it means the user doesn't have `CONNECT` permissions. Add an example of the `ALTER` statement to your question, or better, the relevant code snippets from the deployment script,

Comment: If you are using SSMS< could it be as simple as you haven't refreshed the object explorer?

Comment: Do you have scripts for these logins in SSDT project?

Comment: "In SSMS, the User objects display with a red cross."

Comment: And no I've refreshed countless times

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev yes I have scripts like shown "CREATE USER [..] FOR LOGIN [..]"

Comment: @DanGuzman the cross is on the user only, the login which was created manually does not show a cross

Comment: @AlasdairC, try `GRANT CONNECT TO [...];` and refresh SSMS to see if the red x goes away.

Comment: The Connect permission was there already - I've come up with a solution however, move all my permissions to a Role, and create the user and associate it with a Login and a Role in a Post Deployment script. This means permissions are under version control and this works correctly. There must be something funky happening with the order or creating Roles / Users in the generated publish script from Visual Studio.

Comment: what if load these logins and users via "Database Compare" or "Import database" and check what's the difference? Check the needed login file properties, make sure that it is included to the build.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this is to assume that Users created via SSDT is broken somehow and bypass this entirely..

I moved all my permissions to a Role instead of a User directly.

Then I created a Post Deployment script that creates the User and adds it to the Role. This is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid users/logins within the database. Use Database roles and add your users to the appropriate role(s) rather than grant permissions directly.

If you *really* need to manage logins, you can do that by creating Login objects and processing those, but I find most environments use different logins for different environments.

I ran with Jamie Thomson's code from a while back and blogged about it. That may give you some ideas, but does increase the size of your post-deploy section.
http://schottsql.com/2013/05/14/ssdt-setting-different-permissions-per-environment/

Answer (score 0):

I used to avoid users in the SQL Server Data Tools database project but learned to used them over the years and I ended up using a branching scheme to manage this with different environments since in most cases like Peter Schott stated, different environments have different users. In my projects, I typically setup the structure to look similar to the following:

```
DatabaseName
| - Properties
| - References
| - ChangeScripts
| - SchemaName
| | - Functions
| | - Sequences
| | - Stored Procedures
| | - Tables
| | - Views
| - PublishProfiles
| - Security
| | - CustomRole.sql
| | - Permissions.sql
| | - RoleMemberships.sql
| | - Domain_ManagedServiceAccount_.sql --(The _after the name is reference to $)
| | - Domain_ManagedServiceAccount_Login.sql
```

Inside the user files (Domain_ManagedServiceAccount_.sql above) I place database code similar to the following (which could be for a user or for a group but I am showing syntax for a Managed Service Account):

```
CREATE USER [Domain\ManagedServiceAccount$] FOR LOGIN [Domain\ManagedServiceAccount$];
GO
GRANT CONNECT TO [Domain\ManagedServiceAccount$];
```

The `GRANT CONNECT` is important because without it the user would always lose the permission to connect on deploy and it bugged me until I spent time figuring out what was wrong.

In some solutions, I have multiple database projects and the logins only need to be in one project. The projects that need to have the login (usually one project per solution) are the only projects that have the login file to avoid build errors for the database users in each database project. The server login information is in the login file (Domain_ManagedServiceAccount_Login.sql above) and the code looks similar to the following:

```
CREATE LOGIN [Domain\ManagedServiceAccount$]
     FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english];
```

I manage database role memberships in the RoleMemberships.sql file. That file looks similar to the following:

```
ALTER ROLE [<RoleName>] ADD MEMBER [Domain\ManagedServiceAccount$];
GO
```

With this setup, I no longer need to avoid users on deploy and can fully manage the database users in the database project. I also never need to use a pre- or post-deploy script for users or role memberships. By doing it this way I also was able to use the publish feature so I ended up saving my publish settings to a publish profile and save those under the PublishProfiles folder and deploys are now as easy as going to the publish profile file and clicking the Generate Script or Publish button. Many times, building the solution or project will expose things you may need to fix so you get clean code that sometimes is not obvious when doing schema compares between your project and a database server.

In some ways the downside is I have a bunch of redundant code by having a branch for each environment but on the positive side, I have a replica of a particular environment in the database project environment branch and can make changes there without going to the database until I am ready. I generally use the ChangeScripts section only for production to keep a record of all deployed changes. Another con to using this style of branching is sometimes managing the security changes between branches can be a pain, like adding new users to dev branch and then merging that change to QA and then making sure to not just accept the code from dev that would overwrite your users in QA with dev users. Over the years, I've learned what to look for and that generally means if there is a database.proj change, always use the merge tool to manually merge the changes to be sure it ends up the way I want.

Whether you decide to branch or not, the setup as I use it works to keep a particular database server and the logins and users synchronized with the project and it does not recreate the users unless they don't exist on the server. This is good when restoring production database into an environment that doesn't have the same users and the database publish will handle the user part with ease for that environment.